# how Can i post data to an url using curl and json?

Tags: php, json, api, curl, post

i want to use api of a website for send notification to my app 
and the website help is not good :/

website said you should write in header of request tokan code and some setting 
how can i post json data to this website with php ?
with these header 
"Authorization: Token 7fb1………………………………29b464c "
"Content-Type: application/json"
"Accept: application/json"

and the url is from help text of website 
curl -X POST "https://panel.pushe.co/api/v1/notifications/"

please help me@_@

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, in future question, please try to format you question better (for instance code in code blocks) so it will be easier to read for the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php example from [here](https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl)

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://api.local/rest/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

`$ curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: TOKEN <YOUR_TOKEN>" https://panel.pushe.co/api/v1/notifications/`